# vim: substitute strings of variable length

Tags: vim

The file to be edited is of type markdown, which has multiple sections decorated by a string of `-`, such as:

```
Section 1
---------

Another Section
---------------
```

I would like to change all `-` to `=`. Is there a nice approach in vim to do it? Assume all of the section strings can be identified as `-\+$` in vim, yet with varying length. I searched but didn't find a good solution so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first off, I feel obligated that to mention that there is [a site dedicated to vim questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)...

---

That being said there are a couple of different ways you can achieve this. One way would be to use the "evaluation register" in your substitute command. That would look like this:

```
:%s/-\+/\=repeat('=', len(submatch(0)))
```

This is essentially saying:

> Replace one or more dashes with '=' repeated *n* times, where n is the number of dashes.

That's the most straightforward/obvious way, but it's a little clunky/verbose, which is typical of substitute commands using the evaluation register.

You could also do this with the global command. That would look something like this:

```
:g/^-\+$/norm Vr=
```

This is essentially saying:

> On every line containing nothing but dashes, type `Vr=` as if I had typed it myself.

`V` will visually select the whole line, and `r=` will replace the entire selection with '=' characters.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the site dedicated for vim questions.

Comment: I found `:g/pattern/norm gnr=` is good too. It works for a partial pattern within a line.

Answer (score 3):

You also have `:global` for contextualizing the substitution.

```
:g/^-\+$/s/-/=/g
```